# How do I switch from alignParentLeft to alignParentRIght?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my chat bubble to move to the right side when a different user has sent a message but for some reason it stays on the same side. This is what I've tried:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.bubble.getLayoutParams();
if (message.getPersonId() == MainActivity.getUser().getUserId()) {
      params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 0);
      params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
} else {
      params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
      params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
}
holder.bubble.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? I also tried doing `params.removeRule(int)` but it didn't work either plus I prefer to stay away from that because I want to ensure as much usability as possible in terms of OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add parameters like this way-

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
);

 ------------------------------------
 ----------------------------------
// Creating a new TextView
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText(d.getName());
tv.setTextSize(25);

// Defining the layout parameters of the TextView
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

// Setting the parameters on the TextView
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
b.setLayoutParams(lp);

// Adding the TextView to the RelativeLayout as a child
```

I think, if you follow this way, there will not be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not using `adRule()` properly. Please change and try again:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.bubble.getLayoutParams();
if (message.getPersonId() == MainActivity.getUser().getUserId()) {
    params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
} 
else {
    params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
}
holder.bubble.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by use `addRule()` properly. `addRule(int, int)` is a method provided by the SDK.

Comment: [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.addRule(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int, int)) is for cases where second param is a view id, i.e. when you need to align your view to another view. [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.addRule(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int)) is for cases where you want to move your view using its parent (the RelativeLayout container) as the second param.